# calculate length in \newlength with \dimexpr

Tags: tex-core, lengths

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\begin{document}
(1)

    \newlength{\ccc}{\dimexpr\textwidth-100pt}

% This cause error message: You can't use `\dimexpr' in vertical mode.Why is \dimexpr used here a wrong way?

(2)

    \newdimen\ddd{\dimexpr\textwidth-100pt}

% This also causes error.

(3)

        \def\aaa{\dimexpr\textwidth-100pt}
    
    \rule{\aaa}{10pt}

% This does work.
\end{document}
```

I'm confused. Does that mean length calculation can not be done by `\dimexpr` in `\newlength`?

Comment: newlength only has one argument so the  dimexpr is just  in the preamble not in any command, hence the error

Comment: Newlength defines a new length, it cannot set a value, use setlength to set a value

Comment: You want `\usepackage{calc}\newlength{\ccc}\setlength{\ccc}{\textwidth-100pt}`

Comment: @HenriMenke I would use `\dimexpr` rather than calc, but either work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example (2): `\newdimen` has only one parameters, it declares a new "dimen" variable and sets it to 0pt. It has only one parameter (`\ddd` in your example). The following `{\dimexpr ...}` opens a group `{` and sees `\dimexpr` in vertical mode. TeX does not allow to use `\dimexpr` in this context. You can use `\the\dimexpr...` to print the value, but not `\dimexpr` alone. TeX reports the error.

Your example (3): you define macro (no variable) `\aaa` and it expands to `\dimexpr...`. You use this macro in the context `\hrule height\aaa` wich expands to `\hrule height\dimexpr...`. Now the `\dimexpr` is used in allowed context.

Answer (score 2):

If you try

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\ccc}{10pt}

\the\ccc

\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

Can you see why? Because `\newlength` takes *one* argument, not two, so `{10pt}` is typeset. Next, the value of `\ccc` is shown, which is still `0pt`.

If you do

```
\newlength{\ccc}{\dimexpr\textwidht-100pt}
```

then TeX tries to typeset `{\dimexpr\textwidth-100pt}` which raises an error about `\dimexpr`, which is not legal in that context.

There *is* a rationale. As a general rule, registers should be allocated in the preamble and their value can be set anywhere needed.

***You first allocate the register, then set it.*** Allocation for a new length register is done with `\newlength`; setting a length register is done with `\setlength`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\ccc}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\ccc}{\dimexpr\textwidth-100pt}

\rule{\ccc}{10pt}

\end{document}
```

By the way, if you want to fill the rest of the line with a 4pt thick rule, there is a different method that doesn't require measuring.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\filltoend}{%
  \unskip\nobreak\leaders\hrule height4pt\hfill\mbox{}\par
}

\begin{document}

Some words\filltoend

Some words and some other words
Some words and some other words
Some words and some other words
Some words and some other words
Some words and some other words\filltoend

Some words and some other words
Some words and some other words
Some words and some other words
Some words and some other words
Some words\filltoend

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for yor suggestions especially for the idea of`\filltoend`!! And, if messureing is needed, for exmple, use a `\parbox` to occupy the rest of the line, any trick for it?

Comment: @lyl Didn’t you ask for that elsewhere?

Comment: I wonder if there is way to deal with this problem without using any package.